# no values displaying in the span class element

Tags: javascript, html

Here is the code:

```js
var listener = document.querySelectorAll('#calculator span');

// look at each widget pressed and update calculator
for (var count = 0; count < listener.length; count++) {
  listener[count].onclick = function() {
    update()
  };
}



function update() {
  // Get input of calculator screen and button pressed
  var widget = this.innerHTML;
  var screen = document.querySelector('.screen');
  var screenIn = screen.innerHTML;

  // clear the screen
  if (widget == 'DEL') {
    screen.innerHTML = '';
  }

  // if = sign is pressed, evaluate the screen input
  // TODO: handle special cases (like if the input equation isn't syntactically correct)
  else if (widget == '=') {
    screen.innerHTML = eval(inputEq);
  }

  // change x to * for evaluator
  else if (widget == 'x') {
    screen.innerHTML += '*';
  }

  //clear the text inside the screen
  else if (widget == 'C') {
    screen.innerHTML = "";

  } else {
    screen.innerHTML += widget;
  }

}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
  <script type="text/javascript" src="main.js"></script>
  <link href="css.css" type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" />
</head>

<body>
  <div id="calculator">
    <!-- Screen and clear button -->
    <div class="top">
      <span class="clear">C</span>
      <div class="screen"></div>
    </div>

    <div class="buttons">
      <!-- number operators and other buttons -->
      <span>7</span>
      <span>8</span>
      <span>9</span>
      <span class="operator">DEL</span>
      <span>4</span>
      <span>5</span>
      <span>6</span>
      <span class="operator">/</span>
      <span>1</span>
      <span>2</span>
      <span>3</span>
      <span class="operator">x</span>
      <span>+/-</span>
      <span>0</span>
      <span>.</span>
      <span class="operator">-</span>
      <span>(</span>
      <span>)</span>
      <span class="eval">=</span>
      <span class="operator">+</span>
    </div>
  </div>
</body>

</html>
```

For some reason, none of the span values are showing up on the screen section when clicked. I'm not exactly sure what is going on. I tried various techniques for assigning the update function to the button click, but nothing seems to work. If you guys notice something I don't please let me know.

Here is CSS

```
* {
margin: 0;
padding: 0;
box-sizing: border-box;

font: bold 14px Verdana, Geneva, sans-serif;
}

html {
height: 100%;
background: black;
background-size: cover;
}

#calculator {
width: 325px;
height: auto;
margin: 100px auto;
padding: 20px 20px 9px;
background: #b6ffad;
border-radius: 20px;
box-shadow: 0px 4px #94ce8c, 0px 10px 15px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2);
}

.top span.clear {
float: left;
}

.top .screen {
height: 40px;
width: 212px;

float: right;

padding: 0 10px;

background: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2);
border-radius: 20px;
box-shadow: inset 0px 4px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2);

font-size: 17px;
line-height: 40px;
color: white;
text-shadow: 1px 1px 2px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2);
text-align: right;
letter-spacing: 1px;
}

.buttons, .top {overflow: hidden;}

.buttons span, .top span.clear {
float: left;
position: relative;
top: 0;

cursor: pointer;

width: 66px;
height: 36px;

background: white;
border-radius: 20px;
box-shadow: 0px 4px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2);

margin: 0 7px 11px 0;

color: #565656;
line-height: 36px;
text-align: center;

user-select: none;

transition: all 0.2s ease;
}

.buttons span.operator {
background: #afafaf;
box-shadow: 0px 4px #878787;
margin-right: 0;
color: white;
}

.buttons span.eval {
background: #4c4c4c;
box-shadow: 0px 4px #333333;
color: white;
} 

.top span.clear {
background: #ff9fa8;
box-shadow: 0px 4px #ff7c87;
color: white;
}

.buttons span:hover {
background: #82d179;
box-shadow: 0px 4px #64a05d;
color: white;
}

.buttons span.eval:hover {
background: #e2e2e2;
box-shadow: 0px 4px #bababa;
color: black;
}

.top span.clear:hover {
background: #f68991;
box-shadow: 0px 4px #d3545d;
color: white;
}

.buttons span:active {
box-shadow: 0px 0px #ffffff;
top: 4px;
}

.buttons span.eval:active {
box-shadow: 0px 0px #ffffff;
top: 4px;
}

.top span.clear:active {
top: 4px;
box-shadow: 0px 0px #ffffff;
}
```

Comment: I know the operators may not work yet but my goal is to get the numbers to show up first then tackle the operators

Comment: Don't forget to use !== and === rather than != and == in Javascript unless you have some reason for not using the former.

Comment: good point ill add those changes (since I forgot js converts to the right type if it can). I'm still unsure why nothing is displaying

Comment: I ran your code and it does display those spans. So perhaps I am misunderstanding your question.

Comment: What is the point of your function here? The function is not being called anywhere in your code.

Comment: it does? for some reason on any of my browsers it doesnt display in the screen span when I click the numbers. I'm not sure what is going on. It does the same on virtual box linux Ubuntu using middleman. Did you change anything?

Comment: Got an answer for you with a working jsbin

Comment: Its weird still nothing appears

Comment: Okay guys I added my css file too. Hopefully, this will prove why it won't display

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assigning an onclick handler in this way won't pass automatically pass the clicked element as the context of the handler.  Therefore your references to this inside `update` refer to `window` and not a `<span>` element.

To achieve what you want, amend your .js file as follows:

```
for (var count = 0; count < listener.length; count++) {
  listener[count].onclick = function(event){
//                                     ^---include the event param here

    update(event);
//           ^---- pass the reference to your update function
  };
}

//              v-----define an event parameter 'e' in your update function
function update(e) {

  // Your new widget variable will be:
  var widget = e.target.innerHTML;

  //...include the rest of your code as is
  // apart from:
  else if (widget == '=') {
    //screen.innerHTML = eval(inputEq);
    //                           ^---- inputEq not defined anywhere
    // change to:
    screen.innerHTML = eval(screen.innerHTML);
  }

}
```

[Click here for a jsbin equivalent of the above](https://jsbin.com/salewikiba/edit?html,js,output)

Comment: Thanks for accepting my answer.  If you found my answer useful, an up-vote would be greatly appreciated :)

Comment: I added my CSS file to see if thats why it wont display

Comment: If what won't display?

Comment: Add CSS file to see why it's not displaying. Also, I did run jsbin and only 7 will print to console the other numbers dont work. C works too

Comment: when I press 7 it doesnt appear on the screen for the calculator for my version and yours only 7 and C work the other digits wont write to console

Comment: on your jsbin 7 works not the rest and none of my work using your code.

Comment: I just checked it again and it works for me.  here'es the link again (just in case): https://jsbin.com/kedajoyepo/1/edit?html,js,output.  What browser are you using?

Comment: chrome currently

Comment: no errors from the debugger. It's strange  on your new link nothing after DEL works but  everything before and including DEL work. Next run in jsbin now numbers after 4 dont work

Comment: try this: https://jsbin.com/salewikiba/1/edit?html,css,js,console,output

Comment: Is onclick not supported in chrome anymore?

Comment: That works for all digits, and equals and plus, minus and division

Comment: you're right :) also I was reading and found that on chrome onclick isnt support to prevent cross-site scripting

Comment: Really?  I was testing on Chrome myself (and it is working).  Do you have a link to that article, it sounds a little iffy...

Comment: I'm not sure what else to do I deactivated all my chrome extensions and copy and pasted your js from jsbin to my js file and still nothing displays. Here's the article...
                           https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/contentSecurityPolicy

Comment: it works on Jsfiddle but it wont work in any of my browsers including virtual box Ubuntu running firefox

Comment: Is there a place in windows 10 that would prevent it from running security wise?

Answer (score 1):

You're querying for elements before document is loaded. Either move script just before `</body>` tag (below elements you're querying for), so it will be loaded after elements are there, or put your query (and onclick handlers definition) inside `onload` event handler.

Second thing is update function, and the way you're binding it.

I see that you wish that `this` in your update function would be button element, where innerHTML would be its number or operator. But when you bind update function like you do:

```
listener[count].onclick = function(){update()};
```

Then `this` would be a button inside anonymous function(){} like:

```
listener[count].onclick = function(){
    this.innerHTML; // This would be a number/operator of a button.
    update(); // Function will be called but button wont be its "this" variable, but the window.
};
```

You can either pass this to update as argument or bind update directly like:

```
listener[count].onclick = update;
```

Notice that there is no `()` (call operator), you just passing variable with a function, not its result.

**Edit:**

To explain further, you could move this line:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="main.js"></script>
```

to

```
      <span class="operator">+</span>
    </div>
  </div>
  <script type="text/javascript" src="main.js"></script> <!-- here -->
</body>
```

So the script is fired after elements it depends on are already loaded and known, or, you can start to query for buttons after page loads, so this part:

```
var listener = document.querySelectorAll('#calculator span');

// look at each widget pressed and update calculator
for (var count = 0; count < listener.length; count++) {
  listener[count].onclick = function() {
    update()
  };
}
```

would look like this:

```
onload = function(){
  var listener = document.querySelectorAll('#calculator span');

  // look at each widget pressed and update calculator
  for (var count = 0; count < listener.length; count++) {
    listener[count].onclick = function() {
      update()
    };
  }
}
```

So it is window.onload event handler now.

With the binding update function to button, what I meant was, instead of:

```
for (var count = 0; count < listener.length; count++) {
  listener[count].onclick = function() {
    update()
  };
}
```

do:

```
for (var count = 0; count < listener.length; count++) {
  listener[count].onclick = update;
}
```

So now inside update function, `this` would be button, not a window.

Comment: I did try that before and nothing showed up. So what your saying is the cause is the elements not loading before querying would be the fix needed?

Comment: Thank you that makes more sense now! The issue is weirdly enough I cannot run JS on my machine as whole  (virtual included). I did manage to test in Js fiddle and it works. You're right though I should take into account page may not be loading all elements. Thank you for your update and input :)